# If $G$ is a topological/algebraic group, is there a purely group-theoretic interpretation of $G^0$?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

$G^0$ denotes the connected component of the identity. It's easy to show that $G^0$ is *topologically characteristic* in the sense that it is invariant under every continuous automorphism. Here is a more precise formulation of the title question:

> **Question 1:** Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a (normal/characteristic) subgroup. Is there a topology on $G$ making it into a topological group with $H=G^0$?

This would mean that $G^0$ is not intrinsically group-theoretic, since any subgroup can be $G^0$ in some arbitrary topology.

Here is a related question. Can every finite set be mapped into $G^0$ by some automorphism?

> **Question 2:** Let $G$ be a topological group. Given $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in G$, is there an automorphism $\sigma:G\rightarrow G$ (not necessarily continuous) such that $\sigma(x_1),\ldots,\sigma(x_n)\in G^0$?

Since continuity of $\sigma$ is not required here, the first question would imply that you can replace $G^0$ by any (normal) subgroup $H$ and always send a finite set into any subgroup $H$. This sounds unlikely: for example, take $H=Z(G)$ to be the center, and $x_i$ any noncentral element. Since $Z(G)$ is preserved by all automorphisms, there's no way that noncentral elements can be mapped into it.

For Q2, we know each $x_i$ is in some coset of $G^0$, where we fix a family $S$ of coset representatives. Write $x_i=g_is_i$ where $g_i\in G^0$ and $s_i\in S$. We can attempt $x_i\mapsto s_i$ but there's no reason to believe that this can be extended to an automorphism of $G$. Is there a relevant group-theoretic property that would help this work?

How would things change if $G$ is an algebraic group instead of a topological group?

Comment: Do you require your topological groups to be Hausdorff? If not, just take the indiscrete topology on $H$ and let $G$ be the topological sum of the cosets of $H$.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, what if $G$ is Hausdorff? I'm more interested if $G$ is a linear group with the Zariski topology.

Comment: Clearly it is necessary that $H$ carries a topology making it into a connected topological group. Then you can try the same thing, let $G$ be the topological sum of the cosets. Does that give a group topology on $G$? If I didn't overlook anything, a necessary and sufficient condition is that for all $g\in G$ the conjugation with $g$, $h \mapsto ghg^{-1}$ is a continuous automorphism of $H$. That is clearly a necessary condition for every group topology on $G$ in which $H = G^0$.

Comment: So you can do it (Q1) if and only if you can find a connected group topology on $H$ for which all conjugations with elements of $g$ are continuous automorphisms.

Comment: As for Q2, it is false even with n=1: Consider the product of the additive group of real numbers with $Z/2$.